# How to Implement allreduce or allgather Operations for Objects Serialized with Variable Length?

Tags: c++, mpi

I'm working on a non-distributed library in C++ that offers an object serialization interface. This interface can serialize objects into bitstreams using a method similar to the following:

```cpp
std::stringstream ss;
obj.writeTo(ss);
std::string serialized_obj = ss.str();
```

The size of these serialized objects can **vary** due to internal data structure length changes resulting from computations between objects. Given this variability, I'm seeking recommendations on how to implement allreduce or allgather operations for these serialized objects.

I aim to optimize performance in my scenario, which currently relies on a pure MPI library. I'm uncertain whether Boost MPI can meet these requirements and whether it would incur performance losses (or potentially improve performance). However, introducing such a large dependency solely for these two operations wouldn't be the optimal solution for me personally.

**NOTE**: I'm currently using multiple rounds of butterfly-like `MPI_Send/MPI_Recv` to simulate an `Allreduce` operation and multiple rounds of `MPI_Bcast` to simulate `Allgather`. However, due to load imbalances, these implementations suffer from performance degradation.

Any insights or best practices on how to handle this situation efficiently would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Binary object serialization is hard and a solved problem. My recommendation use an existing library

Comment: Perhaps I didn't express it clearly, the serialization interface has been implemented, but it's difficult to adapt to the native `MPI_Allgather` and `MPI_Allreduce` operations.